# How to insert specific IDs in the scatterplot in R

Tags: r

Here an example of my data:

```
mydf <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 9,4,5,15),
  M1 = c(60,50,40,20,30,45),
  M2 = c(90,80, 30, 33,70,40)
)
```

I want to insert only IDs in the plot in which M1<M2.

Here are the codes that I have used:

```
 library(ggrepel)
    res1<- mydf %>% 
      filter(M1< M2)
    p <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x =  M1, y =    M2,label = ID))+
      geom_text_repel() +
      geom_point(data=res1, 
                 aes(x=M1,y= M2),                       
                 color='red',
                 size=3)
```

I want to remove IDs 9,15 as M1>M2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you the desired plot?

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(M1lower = M1 < M2)

res1<- mydf %>% 
  filter(M1lower == T)

ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x =  M1, y =M2,label = ID, color = M1lower))+
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_text_repel(data=res1, 
                  aes(x=M1,y= M2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, No sorry. This remove circles from the plot.

Comment: Oh I think I see now what you intend to do, I have updated my answer.

Comment: No, sorry, we need to get another colour for the hidden IDs

Comment: That was not clear to me in the original question, but I've updated again.